# Trouble implementing google ads in android studio java

Tags: java, gradle, google-play-services, ads

I get errors whenever i add the `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.6.0'` into my build:gradle (app)

this is my code for build:gradle (app):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    namespace 'com.sp.moneyminds'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sp.moneyminds"
        minSdk 27
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    allprojects {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile){
            options.compilerArgs<<"-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.10.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.4.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.1.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:7.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.webkit:webkit:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.6.0'
}
```

this is my code for build:gradle (project):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2' // Updated to the latest version
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.2.2' apply false // Updated version
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.0' apply false
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

this is the error i get from syncing:
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.6.0
Show in Project Structure dialog
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

I've been troubleshooting for 3 days now. Please help

I've tried chatgpt and using different versions of ads implementations with no luck

Answer (score 0):

try this
make `targetSdk 34` the same like `compileSdk 34`
and delte you old add

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.6.0'
```

and add this

```
implementation group: 'com.google.android.gms', name: 'play-services-ads', version: '22.6.0'
```

try this please and send tell me the result

Comment: i got the same error:
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.6.0 Show in Project Structure dialog Show Details Affected Modules: app

and this error while syncing:
[Fatal Error] play-services-ads-22.6.0.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

Comment: show please alle  the output block Errors, because the build:gradle App and Project , looking very good and clean and you have dependencies and implementation .

Answer (score 0):

I've used an older version of the implementation and it works. version 20.0.0 to be specific. I found that versions newer than that for some reason doesn't work in my app.